# IDL RDFLOAT Undefined

Tags: linux, terminal, interactive, idl-programming-language

I am a beginner in IDL.
I am trying to use RDFLOAT in the following format in a terminal:
`rdfloat,'filename.dat',d,sf,wts`

this is the error I get,

`% Attempt to call undefined procedure/function: 'RDFLOAT'.
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$`

Kindly help me resolve this.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`RDFLOAT` is a third party routine I am not familiar with. Is it a function? Is it in your IDL `!path`?